# Allow Angular to ignore some URLs

Tags: angular, typescript, .htaccess, search-guard

My application with Angular is on example.com and my backend is on example.com/api. My problem is when I want to send a request to the server with the URL https://example.com/api/login/get-cookie, I get an error of HttpErrorResponse. I have just typed the same URL in my browser but I will get redirected to the homepage. So I probably get this error, because my server can never be reached.

How can I allow Angular to ignore all URLs with `example.com/api/*`?

My file *app-routing.modules.ts* looks like this:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [HomeGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent, canActivate: [SearchGuard] },
  { path: 'edit-profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [SearchGuard] }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

*.htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding this redirect will take any url that does not match the paths above and redirect them to the home page. Or depending on your preference you could create a 404 or Error component to show instead with `{ path: '**', component: ErrorComponent }`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [HomeGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent, canActivate: [SearchGuard] },
  { path: 'edit-profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [SearchGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```